# scrapy with selenium error when init webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I try run selenium with scrapy but the following exeception appears. Anybody can help me?

NOTE: I already install geckodriver in /usr/local/bin

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
class Coletor(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'coletor'
    start_urls = ['http://prefeituradecambuci.rj.gov.br/transparencia/licitacoes/']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

[EDIT] I install correct version of geckodriver (linux 64) and the execption change:

```
2017-08-12 15:03:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2017-08-12 15:03:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
2017-08-12 15:03:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-08-12 15:03:45 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:35253/session {"capabilities": {"alwaysMatch": {"acceptInsecureCerts": true, "browserName": "firefox"}, "firstMatch": [{}]}, "desiredCapabilities": {"acceptInsecureCerts": true, "browserName": "firefox"}}
2017-08-12 15:03:45 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2017-08-12 15:03:45 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/commands/runspider.py", line 87, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spidercls, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/crawler.py", line 163, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/crawler.py", line 167, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1274, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/crawler.py", line 90, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/crawler.py", line 71, in crawl
    self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/crawler.py", line 94, in _create_spider
    return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 50, in from_crawler
    spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lsiqueira/TCC/coletor/coletor.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 229, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
  selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

SO: Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64 bit

Comment: How did you install geckodriver? Are you sure you installed 64bit version?

Comment: Are you able to launch Firefox using Selenium outside of your script? Test a simple browser launch in python script

Comment: I install the correct version and exception has changed (edit).

Comment: @LucasSiqueira Leave aside scrapy let us first solve `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities`

Comment: @DebanjanB thank you! I I has updated firefox and has worked fine.